# SQL - nonexisting column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using POSTGRESQL database:

[image: database]

and I need to return customer's first name, last name and sum of hours they kept a film above certain limit, say 10. I wrote such query:

```
SELECT customer.first_name AS first_name, customer.last_name AS last_name,
       DATE_PART('day', rental.return_date - rental.rental_date)*24 + DATE_PART('hour', return_date - rental_date) AS sum
FROM rental JOIN
     customer
     ON rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY sum, first_name, last_name
HAVING MIN(sum) > 10;
```

But it says there is no column such as sum. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You are just missing a bracket !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of DBs do not allow to use alias from Select in Group By on the same level. You either  need to copy the whole aggregate statement into group by or move aggregation to another level.

It is not completely clear what you are trying to do. You said "sum of hours they kept a film", but you don't group by film...

And please don't use keywords as column names.

What I assume might be correct query (again not certain about requirements):

```
select
   a.first_name
,  a.last_name
,  min(a.time_val) as min_time
from ( 
   SELECT customer.first_name AS first_name, customer.last_name AS last_name,
       DATE_PART('day', rental.return_date - rental.rental_date)*24 
       + DATE_PART('hour', return_date - rental_date) AS time_val
   FROM rental 
   JOIN customer
     ON rental.customer_id = customer.customer_id
) as a
where min(a.time_val) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to aggregate by the *unaggregated* columns:

```
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Assuming `customer_id` is unique in the customers table, you can also use that.  Presumably, you want the `sum()` to be a sum of some sort -- because that is problem with the query as well.  Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT c.first_name AS first_name, c.last_name AS last_name,
       SUM(DATE_PART('day', r.return_date - r.rental_date)*24 + DATE_PART('hour', r.return_date - r.rental_date)
          ) AS total_period
FROM customer c JOIN
     rental r
     ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
HAVING SUM(DATE_PART('day', r.return_date - r.rental_date)*24 + DATE_PART('hour', r.return_date - r.rental_date)
          ) > 10;
```

Comment: I tried your example, but I receive "ERROR: column "total_period" does not exist"

Comment: @Ginny . . . Right . . . In Postgres you need to repeat the expression.

Answer (score 0):

select c.first_name, c.last_name,
date_part('day',return_date - rental_date) as sum_of_days
from abc c

In your case, try put the whole part in bracket, then 'as sum_of_days'